# jQuery Sortable Connect Lists - store values in list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking at the demo for sorting items [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) but I want the text in the list to appear as something but when I click save and it posts server side I want to use values. I know `<li>` doesn't support value so what options do I have?

**UPDATE**: I assume the way to save the data server side is to have a hidden input, when the user clicks a save button you populate the hidden field with the sortable.array() data with javascript and then it does the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a form submit handler you can serialize the sortable into a hidden input which will be posted back server side.

In response to your comment - serialize() does indeed work as demo'd [here](http://jsbin.com/iveve)

e.g

```
$('#yourForm').submit( saveSortable );

function saveSortable(){

  $('#hiddenInput').val( $('#sortable').serialize() );

}
```

Comment: $('#sortable').serialize() doesn't return anything

Comment: see http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize. Have you changed 'sortable' to the correct id of your element?

Comment: That would be it! I went with toArray in the end, seems simpler

Comment: I've just realised I need 2 values to post so I have seperated them with a hyphen. Does that make sense. Server side I can then split it.

Comment: either that or two hidden inputs, whatever you feel is best

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data-` attriute as recommended in [HTML5 documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data)

```
<li data-value="the real value">Some Value</li>
```